# mongod not logging after log rotate

Tags: mongodb

Originally, mongod is running and log to  file shard1.log. And I run mongod again and failed.

In the shard1.log, there are only infomation about the failure of second command. The origin log is renamed to shard1.log.2015-02-01T07-41-46.

But the problem is the origin mongod not logging any more.

I check the opened file of origin mongod.

```
ls -l /proc/7980/fd | grep -v socket | grep log

l-wx------ 1 mongodb mongodb 64 2月   6 06:05 1 -> /data/mongodb/log/shard1.log.2015-02-01T07-41-46
```

The shard1.log.2015-02-01T07-41-46  stayed unchanged.

So how can I make the origin mongod log again?

**Edit**

here is my mongo config file

```
logpath=/data/mongodb/log/shard1.log
fork=true
dbpath=/data/mongodb/db/shard1
pidfilepath=/data/mongodb/pid/shard1.pid
shardsvr=true
replSet=shard1/10.0.0.1:27017
port=27017
bind_ip=10.0.0.2
```

the output of command `db.serverCmdLineOpts`

```
{
    "argv" : [
        "/data/mongodb/bin/mongod",
        "-f",
        "/data/mongodb/conf/shard1.conf"
    ],
    "parsed" : {
        "bind_ip" : "10.0.0.2",
        "config" : "/data/mongodb/conf/shard1.conf",
        "dbpath" : "/data/mongodb/db/shard1",
        "fork" : "true",
        "logpath" : "/data/mongodb/log/shard1.log",
        "pidfilepath" : "/data/mongodb/pid/shard1.pid",
        "port" : 27017,
        "replSet" : "shard1/10.0.0.1:27017",
        "shardsvr" : "true"
    },
    "ok" : 1
}
```

Comment: What do you mean "I run mongod again and failed"? What do you have `logpath` set to?

Comment: @wdberkeley I write config to a file, start mongo with this file twice, the latter one failed and the former not logging after the latter one failed

Comment: Can you show us the relevant parts of the config and why it failed the first time? Can you show us the output of [`db.serverCmdLineOpts()`](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/method/db.serverCmdLineOpts/) from the mongod instance that's supposedly not logging? We don't have enough information to figure out why the server may not be logging.

Comment: @wdberkeley see the edit of the question

Comment: Do you know what happened the first time when it failed? What are the latest things in `/data/mongodb/log/shard1.log`?

Comment: @wdberkeley because the former one is running and take up the port. The problem is the latter one cause the log file be rotated and the former not logging any more

Comment: OK, I think I finally see what you mean. It's not clear what the source of the problem is, but I think restarting the mongod process should get it logging again.